# OLS parameter estimation of an expression?

Tags: estimation, least-squares, parameterization

During my research for a class, I came across a paper that said they estimated an equation using OLS. But the parameter they were estimating appeared to be an expression that looked like this (not the actual equation just something I made up to illustrate):

$$ y = \frac{\beta-1}{2}\chi $$

Rather than what I am used to seeing for OLS:

$$ y = \beta_{0}X_{0} + \beta_{1}X_{1} $$

How does one estimated the equation that way? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Could it be that they estimated the expression in front of $X$ as a whole by OLS and then obtained $\beta$ by multiplying the obtained value by two and adding one?

Comment: It would be impossible to tell without a reference or a description of what $\chi$ here is.

Comment: What was the paper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Richard Hardy said in his comment, in this case you can simply estimate $y=\delta X + \epsilon$. Since $\delta = \frac{\beta - 1}{2}$, you can calculate $\beta = 2\delta + 1$. You do this kind of thing when your regression equation comes from a theoretical model.

Standard errors are simple to calculate in a similar way, using the rules for linear transformations of variances.